# Django one-to-one relationships and initial values

Tags: django, django-forms, one-to-one

I´m learning to code and I´m trying to make a small app using Django.

I have two models, Groups and Lists. The idea is that a user creates a Group, and then a List of students (which uses a formset).

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    students_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    second_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.OnetoOneField(Groups, max_length=50, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="Grupo")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

All the students on that list should be assigned to the group you just created. I already set the one-to-one relationship, but in this way, the user has to choose the group for every student (it is supposed that ALL of these students belong to this group, so I think doing this repeatedly is unnecessary).
This is the view:

```
def addList(request):

    AddListFormSet = modelformset_factory(List, 
        fields=("name", "last_name", "second_last_name", "group"), 
    extra=2,)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddListFormSet(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return redirect("/grupos")

    form = AddListFormSet(queryset=List.objects.none())

    return render(request, "new_list.html", {"form": form})
```

How can I pre-assign the group that I just created for all the students that I capture in the next step?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the group id in params from the page where you created the group to the page where you are creating a list. So, then you can use it to auto-populate the list field 'group' in your form.

And also, make the group field editable so while entering data in form, you can change the group out of a drop-down menu of available groups.

Comment: Thanks, I got the first part, now I´m able to pass the id of the group to the next view, but how can I "auto-populate" the Group field in the AddListFormSet? Still don´t get it.

Comment: You can access the form field in HTML using Javascript/jquery or in python inside the form function.